# Bounds for zeta function residue

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and let $c = c(K)$ denote the residue
at $s = 1$ of its zeta function.  It is known [Wikipedia: class number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula)
that c can be determined via
$$c = \frac{2^r (2\pi)^shR} {w\sqrt{(D)}}. $$

Some specific (approximate) numerical values for low degree fields are :
$c = .785$ for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-1}]$, $c= .430$ for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt5]$, $c = .814$ for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]2]$, and of course $c = 1$ for $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.

> Question: What range of values is taken on by $c(K)$ as $K$ varies over quadratic and cubic extensions of the rationals? In particular, what upper bounds are available?

Answer (score 1):

The [Brauer--Siegel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Siegel_theorem) addresses this.  It says that, over families of number fields of fixed degree,  that $\log (h_K R_K)$ is asymptotic to $\log \sqrt{D_K}$.

[This paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/72/1/40.abstract) seems to go into some details on explicit bounds, in the odd degree case.  In the case of quadratic fields, I think the result is ineffective, due to the possibility of [Siegel zeroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero).  (This wikipedia article also briefly discusses the $L$-function estimate the underlies the Brauer--Siegel result in the quadratic case.)